# Gulp copy single file (src pipe dest) with wildcarded directory

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to copy a specific file src `C:\Project\dir1\dirv-1.0.0\tools\file.exe` to a specific directory dest `C:\Project\dir2\` using gulp.

The version number in `dirv-1.0.0` could change in the future, so I want to wildcard the version number.

Here is the task I have for that (`gulpfile.js` is in `C:\Project`):

```
gulp.task('copy', function(){
    return gulp
        .src('dir1\dirv-*\tools\file.exe')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dir2'));
});
```

This ends up generating the following dest file: `C:\Project\dir2\dirv-1.0.0\tools\file.exe`. What I want is `C:\Project\dir2\file.exe`.

How do I do this gulp copy task so that I can wildcard the src path but only copy `file.exe` to the dest path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [gulp-flatten](https://github.com/armed/gulp-flatten)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    return gulp.src('./dir1/dirv-*1/test.txt')
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dir2'));
});
```