# Gulp: copy file to multiple folders starting with specific string

Tags: gulp

I'm working to copy a file **style.scss** from specific directory to multiple folders that start with **skin-**.

In fact, i don't know how to tell gulp to choose folders that start with this string **skin-**.

Here is my gulp code:

```
// Copy Files
gulp.task( "copyFiles" , function() {
    return gulp.src( "app/scss/style.scss" )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( "app/scss/skins/skin-*" ) );
});
```

At command prompt, it says that the task is running but with no result.

I have searched a lot around for that, but i didn't find a method. I found this question here which near to my question context, but it didn't help! [Gulp copy single file (src pipe dest) with wildcarded directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678243/gulp-copy-single-file-src-pipe-dest-with-wildcarded-directory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying only slightly @davidmdem's answer at [saving to multiple destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41812185):

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const glob = require("glob");

const destinationFolders = glob.sync("app/scss/skins/skin-*");    

gulp.task('copyFiles', function () {
  
  var stream = gulp.src("app/scss/style.scss");

  destinationFolders.forEach(function (skinFolder) {
      stream = stream.pipe(gulp.dest(skinFolder));
  });

  return stream;
});
```

You cannot put a glob into `gulp.dest` as you are trying in your question.

Comment: I tested it and it worked successfully! I appreciate that Mark. Thank you.